# Appending datapoints as table to a subplot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have generated different data sets which I analyzed by computing mean values, standard deviation and standard error. 
Then I am displaying these data points as (x,y)-plot as well as a histogram in different subplots.
All this is working just fine. I saved the mean values (and so on) in a cell-matrix which looks more or less like this:

```
[]     A       B       C      D      E
Mean   4.50    9.10    11.00  0.96   7.10 
dev    0.41    1.71    1.43   0.27   0.91
err    0.22    0.43    0.93   0.17   0.70
```

What I am trying is to add this output as a table to another free **specific subplot** in my figure.

Comment: I think that this [matlab answers](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/974-insert-table-into-figure) post is interesting for you. Alterntively, you could try to make an own gui design, but this seems to be a bit overkill.

Comment: @patrik I found that solution as well, but my number of subplots and the subplot in which I want to show the table change from time to time e.g. `subplot(2,2,4)` or `subplot(2,4,6)` thus I would need a method to add the content to a specific subplot I don't know how to edit that solution(your link) to fit my problem.

Comment: You may need to add some code to make it fit. The `uitable` is not a plot, but a structure that you add to the figure. You may need to add some code to suit your needs, eg set the position to `'normalized'`, then let the table appear in the right location with the right size... If you have a 3x2 subplot for example, then then you want the table in the bottom third on either the left or right half. This takes some work, but it is possible to do and it will probably not take hours.

Comment: @patrik you are right, it is quite easy to modify to satisfy my problem, I will post my answer below soon, but it is still bugging me, that you have to change the values of the Position manually to fit the respective subplot. Is there a way to read these values from the figure/subplot? I won't accept my answer for a few days to see if someone finds an automatic solution and if so I will accept rather that one.

Comment: I am not sure if you can read them. It is probably possible if you look at the properties of the uitable. And about setting the positions manually, what I know this is more or less the same as is done for subplot. It is just that subplot is much more elaborated. By setting the `Units` to `'normalized'`, they will rescale when the subplot changes size. You may also want to write a callback function that updates the `uitable` when the window size changes, but that is strictly not necessary. If the code is proper written you will need to do this only once, independent of the number of `subplots`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As patrik posted as comment to the question the problem can be solved with `uitable`. Yet this solution needs to be changed manually to fit respective subplot.

```
uitable('Data', datapoints, 'ColumnName', Col_Names,...
         'RowName', Row_Names, 'Units', 'normalized',...
         'Position', [0.55 0.05 0.4 0.4]);
```

In the posted example I am using the 4th of 4 subplots (2x2).
The values of `'Position'` have to be modified:

- first value equals the distance to the left side of figure
- second value equals the distance to the bottom of the figure
- 3rd value equals the width of the table
- 4th value equals the height of the table

The lower left corner of the figure is 0,0 and the upper right corner is 1,1 (because I used normalized units.

Comment: No it does not. For best result the `'Position'` should be set by a function `position = setTablePosition(m,n,p)`, where `m` and `n` are number of `subplot` rows and columns: and `p` the preffered location. Now, since you use them for creating the `subplot` already they can be made variables. Then you will only need to change the code in one place as before.